# Android webview javascript stops working after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, android-webview

i have site that runs jquery mobile on a webview. When the activity starts everything is working just fine but after the activity is paused for something like 30 minutes or more and i return to the webview, it is not working anymore. It looks like the JavaScript stop responding.

I am loading the webpage with the web.load(url) method.

```
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
private void initUI(View view) 
{
    logger.info("initUI() - Initilazing Fragment UI");
    webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));
    if (webView == null)
    {
        logger.info("initUI() - Creating WebView");
        webView = new WebView(this.getActivity());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        webView.setLayoutParams(layoutParameters);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptUtils(this.getActivity()), "Android");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
             webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(SeeWhatYouLikeWebClientFactory.getWebClient(this));
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new SWYLWebChromeClient());
    }
    // Attach the WebView to its placeholder
    webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
}
```

Thanks